# Appcelerator label with whitespace

Tags: android, label, appcelerator, whitespace

I made a tableview with some labels, the labels all have a border so it looks like a nice table.

However, if the label text is aligned to the right, the text is directly placed against the border. I've tried adding a space after the text, but it seems like Android just trims these spaces.

Is there any way I can create some whitespace between the text and the border? (For example with some character?)

Answer (score 0):

When creating a label you can just add the `right` property to the label.

```
Ti.UI.createLabel({
    right: 5
});
```

or

```
<Label right="5" />
```

You should also not set the border on the label, but wrap the label in a view and set the borders to the view instead!

Comment: That's not the solution: this way the border is also moved

Answer (score 0):

Place a view around the Label and put the border on that view

```
<View borderWidth="1" borderColor="#fff" width="Ti.UI.FILL" height="Ti.UI.SIZE">
  <Label text="test" width="Ti.UI.SIZE" height="Ti.UI.SIZE" right="5"/>
</View>
```